# Filter by id as well as text in Select2

Tags: jquery-select2

```
var data = [{ id: 11-07, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 11-04, text: 'bug' }, 
            { id: 11-08, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 11-09, text: 'invalid' }, 
            { id: 11-10, text: 'wontfix' }];

$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
data: data
})
<select class="js-example-data-array"></select>
```

I want to filter the select2 with both id as well as text. By default , it filters by text.
How can I filter by id as well?

Answer (score 1):

You must use "matcher".

```
$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
  data: data,
  matcher: function(term, text, option) {
    return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0 || option.val().toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0;
  }
})
```

It will return result filtered by text or id.

Answer (score 0):

Use a a custom matcher. Add a property "matcher" with an custom function so you can match it your self. For explanation check the [examples page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html).
To match against the id you need to use a 'complex matcher'. More info about that can be found [here](https://select2.github.io/options.html#matcher).

Answer (score 0):

For the current 4th version the function for the `matcher` must be written differently. This code is based on an [example](https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched) from the documentation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{ id: '11-07', text: 'enhancement' }, { id: '11-04', text: 'bug' }, 
              { id: '11-08', text: 'duplicate' }, { id: '11-09', text: 'invalid' }, 
              { id: '11-10', text: 'wontfix' }];

  function matchCustom(params, data) {
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
    }

    // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }

    // search by value
    if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
      return data;
    }

    // search by id
    if (data.id.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
      return data;
    }

    // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return null;
  }

  $(".js-example-data-array").select2({
    data: data,
    matcher: matchCustom
  });
});
```

```css
.js-example-data-array {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select class="js-example-data-array"></select>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```